# what is best way to test a ported compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, cross-compiling

I am about to start porting the llvm compiler to a new arch. My question is - Once I think I finished porting it, how can I test it ? is there an open source simulation ?

Comment: not related to your question, but I am interested: are you writing the back-end? From 0?

Comment: Its based on another arch with several modifications. So I intend just to use that arch as a base to my compiler.

Comment: Usual toolbox: gcc torture testsuite and csmith.

Answer (score 1):

For start, you could make some skeletons programs (some `Hello words`) in which you gradually add instructions from `int main() {}` until you are confident you tested most of the arch's instructions (you'll have to look at the generated asm).

Once those run ok, the next step  is to compile and run some existing real-world programs (doesn't matter what they do) and see:

1. if they compile and run correctly
2. how they compare with some other existing compilers for that arch (if they exist).

Lastly you could search for some benchmarks for this specific arch if they exists.

Comment: Also enable as many possible checks and debug output within the backend. If errors happen during codegen/optimization (colouring, spilling, coagulating), you need to know.  Parameter passing and all aspects of stack frame generation is typically the first thing to test.